# express server unresponsive after 5 POST's

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am using express to serve a single page webapp, and as a REST endpoint for said app. Everything works fine for the static page serving, but after 5 posts the server becomes unresponsive. I have seen a lot of other posts with this problem but they all say to just make sure to call res.send() or res.end() which i do in every call somewhere, regardless of how the logic branches. The app.js code is below.

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express'),
  http = require('http'),
  path = require('path');

var app = express();
var auth = require("./controllers/authentication.js");

http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 100;

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});

app.get('/public/*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('.'+req.url);
});

app.post('/auth/login', function(req, res, next) {
  auth.login(req, res, next);
});

app.post('/auth/logout', function(req, res, next) {
  auth.logout(req, res, next);
});

app.post('/auth/verify', function(req, res, next) {
  auth.verify(req, res, next, function(req, res, next) {
    res.conentType = 'json';
    res.send(200, "authorized");
  });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

and here is the command line output that i get (i tried issuing other requests after, but the server would not process them). I assume that I am somehow not terminating the connection properly, but cant figure out how.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

problem was related to not closing mysql connection pool